# Spyder No module named ‘seaborn’

Tags: python, seaborn, spyder

The module calls for the library Seaborn to be imported using import seaborn as sns. I get an error that says
File “C:\Users\tyebr.spyder-py3\temp.py”, line 9, in
import seaborn as sns

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘seaborn’

I’ve gone into the command prompt and installed seaborn. Then closed and re-opened sypder and tried again with the same results. What’s the next troubleshooting steps to pursue?

Image of Seaborn installation
image

Comment: What exact command did you use to install seaborn?

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#i-cant-import-seaborn-even-though-its-definitely-installed

Comment: This has been fixed.  Anaconda had an upgrade notice.  An error occurred when I attempted to upgrade so I deleted and installed the new version.  It’s working fine now.